# What causes tires to squeal when turning a corner

Tags: tires

When turning a corner I've been hearing the tyres squeal. I'd like to have an understanding of what might cause it so I could understand if it's related to a recent service and have sensible discussions when trying to diagnose the issue

Comment: Are the tires correctly inflated? Have you checked them with a known good gauge?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I asked the garage and they said they put the level higher e.g. 38 psi and that I should try 32 to see if it reduces the noise. When I went to the local service station to pump it up the machine said it was at 29. I'm not sure yet if it's made a difference. Is above or below more likely to cause a squeeling noise.

Comment: Lower-than-spec pressure is much more likely to result in squealing when turning.   If I were you, I would set the pressure to the car manufacturer's specs using a known good gauge.

Comment: That usually means too high a speed...

Comment: Could you give us some info about your vehicle? Also be aware that new tyres may squeal for a few miles...

Comment: What is the make, model and year of the car? And what work have you had done on it recently? Also, how is this different from your other posted question about squeaking?

Comment: Is it the tyres squealing? If this happens at comparatively low speeds then the power steering belt may need replacing. More information is needed for a diagnosis.

Answer (score 2):

You asked,

> What causes tires to squeal when turning a corner?

In the literal sense, tires squeal when they begin to slide against the road surface. The rubber sliding on the hard surface is what produces the squealing noise.

The next logical question is, why are my tires starting to slide on the road?

There could be a number of reasons for that. Considering the context of your question (you're asking about squealing in a turn), there are a few likely scenarios:

- You're driving really fast and exceeding the natural grip of the tires. The tread on the tires is squealing as it loses grip.
- Your tires are underinflated. Tires need the correct air pressure to retain their intended shape and structure. If a tire is underinflated, it will tend to be soft from a structural perspective. When you side-load an underinflated tire, it can start to "roll" such that the tire deforms far enough that the sidewall starts to make contact with the road surface. As the tire deforms, even if the tread itself retains grip, the sidewall typically gets "dragged" against the tarmac, and makes a squealing noise.
- Tires that are severely worn or not correctly matched to your vehicle in terms of load rating or other specifications can deform or lose grip and cause squealing.

You haven't mentioned severe tire wear or grossly incorrect tire size or spec, but if you're unsure of the condition or suitability of your tires with respect to your vehicle, it's good to verify that first.

After that, Since you've indicated in your question that there was recent service, and it's questionable whether or not your tires are inflated correctly (the shop told you 39, and you measured 29), the best next step is to correctly inflate your tires to the pressure recommended by you vehicle's manufacturer. Note that this is *not* the pressure stamped on the sidewall of the tire. If you don't have your owner's manual, you can look inside the door jambs for a sticker indicating the correct pressures. And make sure your're measuring with a gauge you trust, and that you understand the impact of temperature if you're measuring the tires when they are extremely cold or hot.

Answer (score 1):

Poor misalignment can cause tires to squeal. This can happen if a service was performed on the steering or suspension, and care was not taken to align the tires after the service (and if care was not taken during the service to not throw the alignment completely off).